# Describing data models in Javascript

Tags: javascript, model, dto

I search library that allows to describe data structures.
For example i have an application. It receives data with XHR and checks response json.

When response is complex validate it with imperative code is complex too.
I want describe such models/structures/DTOs declaratively and then use it with something like:

```
var Human = Model.define({
    head: Head,
    limbs: List(Hand, {min: 0, max: 2}),
    ...
});

try {
    var human = Human.load(anyJsonStringOrObject);
} catch (e) {
    console.log('Error loading model');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are looking for [js-model](http://benpickles.github.io/js-model/)

here some examples from its docs:

```
var Project = Model("project", function() {
  this.extend({
    find_by_title: function(title) {
      return this.detect(function() {
        return this.attr("title") == title
      })
    }
  })
})

Project.find_by_title("stuff")
```

Comment: It looks like i searched. Thanks. I try it and then accept answer.